# Python - How to reference a global variable from a function

Tags: python, scope

I must be missing some very basic concept about Python's variable's scopes, but I couldn't figure out what.

I'm writing a simple script in which I would like to access a variable that is declared outside the scope of the function :

```
counter = 0

def howManyTimesAmICalled():
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

howManyTimesAmICalled()
```

Unexpectedly for me, when running I get :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment
```

Adding a global declaration at the first line

```
global counter
def howManyTimesAmICalled():
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

howManyTimesAmICalled()
```

did not change the error message.

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add `global counter` in the first line of the `howManyTimeAmICalled` function ?

Comment: @karthikr - I have edited my question to make it clear. Sukrit Kalra 's answer clarifies that indeed it is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `global counter` inside the function definition. (Not in the first line of your code)

Your code should be

```
counter = 0

def howManyTimesAmICalled():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

howManyTimesAmICalled()
```

Comment: fyi: that signals to use the counter from the global registry rather than the local one