# How to reference a global variable in more than one function?

Tags: python

I've got headache with the global variable reference problem in a simple word frequency count program. I check the the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17928804/2185472) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814468/2185472), and the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html); however, I still haven't got the idea of global variable reference.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('c:/Users/Nick/Downloads/sample_file.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().lower().split()

c = Counter(words)

total_words = sum(c.values())


def top_n_words(n):
    global c
    # c = Counter(words)
    top_n = c.most_common(n)
    print("Top %d words are:" % n)
    print("-" * 20)
    for w, c in top_n:
        # print("%10s: %-10s" % (w, c))
        print("{word:>10s}: {counts:<10d}".format(word=w, counts=c))


def word_appears(w):
    # global c
    c = Counter(words)
    print("The word '{word:s}' appears {time:d} times.".format(word = w, time = c[w]))


top_n_words(12)
print("-" * 20)
print("Total words: %d" % total_words)
print("Total words: {t:d}".format(t=sum(c.values())))
word_appears("history")
```

1. In the `top_n_words` function, I've declare that `c` is global. Should I declare it global in `word_appears` function? It doesn't work.
2. Why I can't reference to the `c` in the `print` function? Does the order of the `top_n_words`, `word_appears` affect the final print function?
3. What is a good practice to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: I dont see the need to reference it. It is a global variable after if can be used anywhere. The best to do it would be is to create two separate local variables and play around with them in the function.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @RickTeachey I'm using python 3.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all code in functions and use only arguments to make the counter available. For example:

```
from collections import Counter


def read_words(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        words = f.read().lower().split()
    return words


def top_n_words(counter, n):
    top_n = counter.most_common(n)
    print("Top %d words are:" % n)
    print("-" * 20)
    for w, c in top_n:
        # print("%10s: %-10s" % (w, c))
        print("{word:>10s}: {counts:<10d}".format(word=w, counts=c))


def word_appears(counter, w):
    print("The word '{word:s}' appears {time:d} times.".format(word=w,
        time=counter[w]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def main(file_name):
        words = read_words(file_name)
        counter = Counter(words)
        top_n_words(counter, 12)
        print("-" * 20)
        print("Total words: %d" % len(words))
        word_appears(counter, "history")

    main('words.txt')
```

Comment: `Put all code in functions and use only arguments to make the counter available` This makes things clear! Thank you for your kind to starters.